# GeForce and Quadro Card Driver

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a computer with two graphics cards installed (a GeForce GT 610 and a Quadro NVS 290), and have monitors connected to each of these cards.

I'm not sure what driver is best to use for them though. I am looking to get the best graphics performance out of both of them. (I am using the 610 for more graphics intensive applications like Dolphin Emulator and the NVS 290 to connect extra monitors, so it will mostly run Windows Aero.) Which of these drivers will have better performance/compatibility with these cards?

GeForce: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/130631/en-us

Quadro: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/110262/en-us

Comment: Is there a reason not to load the correct driver for each card?

Comment: Only one Nvidia driver can be installed at once, since the second will overwrite the first.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks! Installing one at a time and allowing Windows to install each driver ended up solving the problem. It still overwrites the driver listing in control panel but it still remains installed on the card.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check device manager after you install both drivers. Each card should be installed with it's correct drivers after both installs. It may overwrite with the newest Nvidia control panel or GeForce experience. But the drivers should be correctly installed afterwards.